# Undefined index notice while requesting ajax with HTML5 pushstate

Tags: php, ajax, html, notice

Maybe this script is outdated, but however i want to know how to fix this problem. I am getting `Notice: Undefined index:` notice/error when page requests ajax call. Everything works, just this notice/error bothers me. Maybe i am asking this wrongly, but how to fix this?

**PHP**

```
<?php
  if($_GET['type']!='ajax'){
    include 'header.php';
    echo "<div id='result-content'>";
  }
?>

content goes here

<?php
  if($_GET['type']!='ajax'){
    echo "</div>";
    include 'footer.php';
}
?>
```

**JS**

```
$.thisproblem = $.thisproblem || {};
$.thisproblem.loadContent = function () {
    $('.ajax-loader').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: pageUrl + '?type=ajax',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result-content').html(data);
            $('.ajax-loader').hide();
        }
    });
    if (pageUrl != window.location) {
        window.history.pushState({path: pageUrl}, '', pageUrl);
    }
}

$("a").on('click', function (e) {
    pageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    $.thisproblem.loadContent();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Sorry for bad english and thanks for any answers.

Comment: Use `isset()` and change your php to `if( !isset($_GET['type']) || $_GET['type']!='ajax'){` so that it checks if `$_GET['type']` is set before trying to check its value.

Comment: Thank you. Please wrote your answer. I want to accept it.

Comment: @Sean Your suggestion avoids the warning message, but since the query string is hard coded in the AJAX call, one wonders why the `type` value is absent when PHP runs the script.

Comment: @Hobo Sapiens, am i mistaken, or you just said, that this js or php code is wrong? Maybe any suggestions to how to make it more "lovely"?

Comment: I didn't say your code is wrong. I said that the JS and PHP code should work together (at least, this warning shouldn't appear) and that Sean's work-around is hiding the true cause of the problem. If you don't know what the problem is you don't know what bad side-effects it might cause. Unfortunately, there's not enough information here to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @HoboSapiens it is in the `$.ajax()` but it is not in `window.history.pushState({ path: pageUrl }, '', pageUrl);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `?type` is only set/used in your `$.ajax()` url, you will want to use `!isset()` to check if it is set before trying to check its value

```
<?php
  if( !isset($_GET['type']) || $_GET['type']!='ajax'){
    include 'header.php';
    echo "<div id='result-content'>";
  }
?>

content goes here

<?php
  if( !isset($_GET['type']) || $_GET['type']!='ajax'){
    echo "</div>";
    include 'footer.php';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTICE Undefined index occurs when the index is not set and you are trying to use it.
For eg: $_GET['type'] will not be set in your case.  So first you need to check if it is set or not.  So you can do

If(isset ($_GET['type'])  || $_GET['type']!='yourvalue'){